# Running queries against multiple servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I am not sure what the best design pattern for this problem is so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have two SQL Servers `A` (with DBs P,Q,R) and `B` (with DBs X,Y,Z).

What is an efficient way to do a join of tables situated on Server `A` with those on Server `B` from command-line? Basically, I am trying to automate a long running list of queries and am not really sure how to proceed.

**EDIT:** I do not have control over the servers and am not an admin.

Comment: `I do not have control over the servers and am not an admin.` Are the admins willing to work with you?

Comment: I just pinged them about this but am assuming the worst case for the moment. Would you think this can be done through Business Intelligence Studio by any chance? On a parallel note, I have the ability to create temp tables on either servers so not sure if this could be of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum I would create a [Link Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) between the two servers.  Using something like [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) will be slower than using a Link Server.

Depending on how fast you need these queries to run you might consider having a nightly process that copies the data from Server A to Server b (or the other way around) so that you don't need to worry about cross server.

Comment: +1 OPENROWSET might work. I will check this and get back. Thank you.

Comment: Ok so unfortunately, I get this error message: `SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.` So guess I am out of luck.

Comment: Go to the DBA's office and start stomping your feet.  You can only do so much without their help...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of performing a join across different servers. You can either use a cluster solution on top of those servers to do it for you, or you can do it by yourself - reading from one table, and performing the join manually in your code.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I am first trying for a pure T-SQL based approach failing which I will resort to writing a C# application layer.